# How do i Extract HTTPResponseMessage content from Console App

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, console-application, httpresponsemessage

I am making a call to Web API from my Console App. I get `HttpResponseMessage` as the response. I am unable to read that message content.

I tried

```
   var loginResult = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<loginresult>(new List<MediaTypeFormatter> { new JsonMediaTypeFormatter() });
```

Visual studio complains that `ReadAsAsync` doesn't exist and also `MediaTypeFormatter` doesn't exist.

But it makes sense why it's not working, because It uses `MediaFormatters` which are specific to MVC.  `ReadAsAsync` also doesn't support console apps.

How do i read `HTTPResponseMessage` content in Console App ?

Comment: "it's not working"  in what way?

Comment: Visual studio complains that `ReadAsAsync` doesn't exist and also `MediaTypeFormatter` doesn't exist.

Comment: Do you have references to System.Net.Http on your project?

Comment: Yes, i have, Otherwise i cannot call `webapi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are missing a reference to the `System.Net.Http.Formatting` assembly. You can get it on [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension/).

Here's the `ReadAsAsync<T>` [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944541(v=vs.108).aspx)

Comment: I tried that already, but i dont think `Console App` has support for `System.Net.Http.Formatting`

Comment: Hey @Venky, I have some console applications referencing the assembly so it should be working for you. What issue did you have that lead you to believe that it's unsupported?

Comment: I couldn't find this dll in `Add Reference` Assemblies. Also, I couldn't find it in Nuget when i search for it.   I thought this dll would be installed automatically as dependency while installing `system.net.http`  i tried it but it didn't install it.

Comment: This is the link to the [Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension/) that contains the `System.Net.Http.Formatting` assembly. BTW, it's not a dependency of `System.Net.Http`

Comment: Cool. It works.. I had to install manually from  Nuget Package Manager Console.

Comment: Glad I could help! Happy coding.